Issue with 'Destination port unreachable" when installing linux
I'm currently trying to install Arch Linux on a new disk, but I'm encountering a networking issue that I can't seem to resolve. I'm getting a "Destination Port Unreachable" error when I try to ping external addresses (e.g., Google DNS at 8.8.8.8). Here are the details:

Connection Type: Wired Ethernet

Router: I can successfully ping my router (192.168.0.1) from the Arch Linux environment.

Current OS: Live USB with Arch Linux

Other OS: On the same machine, everything works perfectly on Windows.


Background:
I previously had Kali Linux installed on this disk, but the internet suddenly stopped working entirely from one day to the next. I backed up the necessary data and formatted the disk. Now, I'm trying to install a new system, and this is the situation.
Additional Notes:

No NAT Issues: Other devices, including the same machine on Windows, connect to the internet without problems.

No DHCP Issues: IP address and default gateway are correctly assigned.


Current Symptoms:

Can't ping external IP addresses (e.g., 8.8.8.8) - "Destination Port Unreachable".

Local network (router ping) works fine.


What i have tried so far:

Interface Status: Checked and the interface enp3s0 is UP and has an IP assigned (192.168.0.111).

Routing Table:
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.111 metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.111 metric 100
192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.111 metric 100


DNS Configuration: Manually set DNS in /etc/resolv.conf:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Restarted systemd-resolved but still no luck.

Log Checks: Reviewed journalctl -xe but didn't find any network-related errors.

Firewall: No firewall rules blocking traffic (iptables -L shows no blocks).

Attempted Diagnostics:

Tried traceroute but can't install it without internet.

Can't use arp as the command isn't available in the live environment.




Any advice on what I might be missing or what additional steps I should take would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

What is the exact message you get from ping?

"From XiaoQiang (192.168.0.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable"

BTW, you can use tracepath (already installed) instead of traceroute.

yes i can. when i used it on google.com it showed: `1?: [LOCALHOST] pmtu 1500    1: XiaoQiang 1.361ms     1: XiaoQiang 0.884ms     2: XiaoQiang 1.144ms pmtu 1480      2. XiaoQiang 0.591ms reached      Resume: pmtu 1480 hops 2 back 1
